# How to measure FTP transfer speed in PHP when connected to FTP via PHP functions

Tags: php, ftp, benchmarking

I am connected to the server via the PHP `ftp_` functions.

How can I measure the transfer speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I brutalized the phihag's code to check non-blocking upload speed. You can't use `ftp_size()` while non-blocking transfer is ongoing, therefore you need a secondary connection just for that purpose. I'm displaying current speed, average speed, elapsed time and estimated time left.

```
$primary_connection = ftp_connect($server);
$secondary_connection = ftp_connect($server);

$mode = FTP_BINARY;
$login = ftp_login($primary_connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$login2 = ftp_login($secondary_connection, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

if (!$primary_connection || !$login) { die('Connection attempt failed!'); }
ftp_pasv($primary_connection,TRUE);
ftp_pasv($secondary_connection,TRUE);

$upload_status=ftp_nb_put($primary_connection, $destination_file, $source_file, $mode);

define('ALPHA', 0.2); // Weight factor of new calculations, between 0 and 1
$filesize=filesize($source_file);
$transferred = 0;
$rate = 0;
$time = microtime(true);

$start_time=$time;

while($upload_status == FTP_MOREDATA){

    $upload_status = ftp_nb_continue($primary_connection);

    $sizeNow=ftp_size($secondary_connection,$destination_file);
    $sizeNowkB=$sizeNow/1024;
    $timeNow = microtime(true);

    $currentRate = ($sizeNow - $transferred) / ($timeNow - $time);
    $currentkBRate = $currentRate / 1024;

    $rate = ALPHA * $currentRate + (1 - ALPHA) * $rate;
    $time = $timeNow;
    $transferred = $sizeNow;

    printf("Uploading file: %s",$source_file);
    echo "<br>\n";

    printf( "To be transferred: %0.2f kB", $filesize/1024);
    echo "<br>\n";

    printf( "Transferred: %0.2f kB", $sizeNowkB);
    echo "<br>\n";

    printf( "Current speed: %0.2f kB/s", $currentkBRate);
    echo "<br>\n";

    printf( "Average speed: %0.2f kB/s", $rate/1024);
    echo "<br>\n";

    $elapsed_time=$timeNow - $start_time;
    printf( "Elapsed time: %0.2f s", $elapsed_time);
    echo "<br>\n";

    if($rate!=0){
        $eta=$filesize/$rate - $elapsed_time;
    }else{
        $eta=0.0;
    }
    if($eta<=0){
        $eta=0.0;
    };
    printf( "Estimated time left: %0.2f s", $eta);
    echo "<br>\n";

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the non-blocking ftp functions to download the file and calculate the time and file size differences. Below is a simple demo with exponential smoothing to prevent the speed from jumping too much:

```
define('ALPHA', 0.2); // Weight factor of new calculations, between 0 and 1
$ftp = ftp_connect(...);
$tmp = ftp_nb_get($ftp, $filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY);
$transferred = 0;
$rate = 0;
$time = microtime(true);
while ($tmp == FTP_MOREDATA) {
   $tmp = ftp_nb_continue($ftp);

   $timeNow = microtime(true);
   $sizeNow = filesize($filename);
   $currentRate = ($sizeNow - $transferred) / ($timeNow - $time);
   $rate = ALPHA * $currentRate + (1 - ALPHA) * $rate;
   $time = $timeNow;
   $transferred = $sizeNow;

   echo "Current transfer speed: $rate B/s\n";
}
```

If you want same thing for `ftp_nb_put()` upload, you would have to replace `filesize($filename)` with `ftp_size($ftp2,$filename)`, where `$ftp2` would have to be a second, identical connection, used just to ask for size of remote file, because `ftp_size()` will not work with your primary connection, while non-blocking transfer is in progress.

Answer (score 2):

1. Before transferring, put the current timestamp into a variable.
2. Determine the size of your file you want to transfer.
3. Transfer the file with the `ftp` functions
4. Get another timestamp and subtract this from the first timestamp.
5. Divide the filesize with the result, then you have the kb/sec.

Example:

```
$start = mktime(); // 1
$size = filesize('yourfile.txt') / 1024 ; // 2 <- to get the KB 

... do your transfer... // 3

//after ftp transfer 
$stop = mktime(); // 4
$duration = $stop - $start; 
$speed = $size / $duration; // 5
```

This basically gives you the speed after the transfer. If you want the speed while transferring, there are other ways of doing it.

Comment: If you divide the filesize by the difference between the second and first timestamp, you'll get the bytes per second, not the kilobytes per second.

Comment: Very true, but it basically does the job. I'll elaborate with more details.